# virtual directory for a domain folder when IIS is not on the domain

Tags: iis, virtual-directory

I have set up a Windows 2012 R2 Server not on the domain as I understand that is better security for the IIS server not to be on the domain.

However I want the website user to have read only links to certain documents on an folder that is on one of the computers on the domain.

To set this up I created a work group user with access to the share. In the basic settings of the virtual directory I am attempting to connect as this user.  However when I test settings both Authentication and Authorization fail.

Is my thinking right that it is best if the web server is not on the domain?
I think the errors may be to do with the error 1219

Comment: The only time not to join an IIS host to a domain is using Specialized Security – Limited Functionality (SSLF) configurations which are designed specifically for very hostile environments under significant risk of attack.

Answer (score 1):

Is this an internal Web Server? if it is I see no reason why it shouldn't be domain joined. as long as you keep up to date with Patching / Monitoring / best practices.

lots of Server 2012 R2 roles that are domain joined use IIS, From RMS and Federation services to Work Folders.

I don't know about your specific app are there might be other reasons why it needs to be in a work group but IIS can happily be deployed in a domain.

Comment: The Web Server hosts a public web site.